# Vuejs vee validate validating all form inputs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Am mtrying to validate all inputs via

```
 this.validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
               console.log(result)
            }).catch(() => {
                // something went wrong (non-validation related).
                return false;
            });
```

But am getting an error

```
 Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

When i check on

```
console.log(this.validator)
```

the function validateAll doesn't exists.Previously the above was working untill today

The following is my package.json dependency

```
 "devDependencies": {
     "vue": "^2.1.10"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-rc.21",
   }
```

What could be wrong as it started throwing errors after running

```
npm install vee-validate --save
```

What do i need to do as it was previously working?

Comment: Maybe `$validator`?

Comment: even when using $validator am still getting the error on the console but the validation is working

Answer (score 1):

`This.validator` means you want to access to a Vue component property. But the plugin use `this.$validator` wich is an injected property by the plugin itself.

http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/examples.html#validate-form

Comment: even when using $validator am still getting the error on the console but the validation is working

Comment: So provide us a test link to see the bug in action.